# XML Property 'InnerText' is WriteOnly when trying to read attribute value

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, entity-attribute-value, innertext

I'm getting a "Property 'InnerText' is WriteOnly" error when trying to read an attribute value

Here's my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<products>
    <product ID="11837">
        <price currency="EUR">75.29</price>
        <properties>
            <property name="brand">
                <value></value>
            </property>
    </properties>
<variations/>
</product>
</products>
```

To extract the price I do:

```
node.SelectSingleNode("price").InnerText
```

which returns "75.29"

But when I do:

```
node.Attributes("ID").InnerText
```

I get the error:

Property 'InnerText' is WriteOnly

I don't see any reason why it's write-only and don't know how I can change it so I can read the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a fact of the implementation of `XmlAttribute` that it only supports writing to its `InnerText` property. You don't "change it" so that you can read the value - you use the [`Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.value.aspx) property:

> Gets or sets the value of the node.

Alternatively, you can access the value via `InnerText` if you cast the `XmlAttribute` as an `XmlNode` (its base class).

Comment: Turns out it has to do with the base class. As I was looping through my results:
For Each node In nodeList, I had not declared the type of node. I noticed this as IntelliSense was not suggesting me the InnerText or Value methods. I now declared 'Dim node As XmlNode' (which I removed earlier) above my loop and it works again. Also by using the Innertext method and not the Value method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlattribute.innertext.aspx):

> The concatenated values of the node and all its children. For attribute nodes, this property has the same functionality as the Value property.

You should just use the `Value` property, instead, like this:

```
node.Attributes("ID").Value
```

Or you can cast it to an `XmlNode` and then access the `InnerText`.  `XmlNode` is the base class for `XmlAttribute`, and its `InnerText` property is read-write rather than write-only.  For instance:

```
CType(node.Attributes("ID"), XmlNode).InnerText
```

I'm not sure why it's write-only in the `XmlAttribute` class.  Presumably there must have been some good reason for it, given the internal workings of the class, though it's hard to imagine what that would be.  The odd thing is that in the MSDN documentation in version 1.1 actually says that it is a read/write property in that version of the framework.  Then, in versions 2.0 - 4.0 it defines the property as write-only, but the description of it says "Gets or sets..."  So, the MSDN hasn't exactly been consistent about it.